# Change the field with UUID_Short failed?

Tags: mysql, uuid, alter-table

I'm trying to alter current `id` field in `organization` table to UUID_SHORT but failed?

```
ALTER TABLE `organization` CHANGE `id` `id` BIGINT(16) UNSIGNED 
 NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_short();
```

I don't see any error message?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set the default value for `id` like this

Rather you can create a trigger to do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_organization
  BEFORE INSERT ON organization 
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.id = uuid_short();
```